# Getting textbox string into property with validation 0

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am a total beginner to C# / Visual Studio and need a shove in the right direction here.

I've got a Main Window.xaml.cs file in which I have a TextBox to receive a first name, as well as two buttons, "Set" to update a class called Student which contains a private property for that and a "Clear" button which is working fine.

I cannot figure out how to get my string from the text box into my Student class and need to get this right before I add more properties.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Main window code is as below

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Clear();

    }
```

My Student class code is as below

```
namespace StudentRecordsSystem
{
public class Student
{
    private string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
           throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            // check that string is not empty

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == true)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Please enter a first name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, you better get some tutorials before posting here. This is not how you implement a Class and that's just one of the things that is not right. I don't want to be rude, but check this out first: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=C%23+tutorial

Comment: Tico is right, but that's no help - i understand. Look for visibility (private, public), property and field variable, and object lifecycle.

Comment: Since you're using WPF I suggest start by doing it in proper WPF way. take a look at my answer. once you used to it, its much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set your FirstName property to public, there's no need to make it private.

You would need to instantiate your student class and then assign the value of the textbox to the property.

```
private Student s;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    s = new Student()
}
private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    s.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
}
```

If you notice that you can't access the Student class from your Form code, check your namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to you could make a constructor for the student class, like so:

```
public Student(string firstName)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
}
```

This would allow you to do something like this:

Student s = new Student("Josh");

Notice that the firstName in the declaration of this method has a lower case f, whereas the variable (in my usage at least) has an upper case F. This is not conventional, I believe the convention is to use camelcase, but to put an underscore (_) in front of private variables. This is primarily a C++ convention, but as C# is designed to look similar to C++, it is suited to the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in xaml.cs:

notice how the DataContext is created and being used to retrieve data.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new Student();
}
private void Clear_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Student)DataContext).FirstName = string.Empty;
}
```

Add this class to the same Project as MainWindow:

the point of using a ValidationRule is that avoid annoying messageBox and instead to mark its control when the rule is violated.

```
public class NamesValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public string MinimumLetters { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if(str == null)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter first name");
        if(str.Length < Convert.ToInt32(MinimumLetters))
            return new ValidationResult(false, string.Format("Minimum Letters should be {0}", MinimumLetters));
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);    
    }
}
```

in xaml:

add xmlns... to the first of the xaml, and then use Binding to read/write data from/to FirstName. also notice the validation rule added to the binding.

note: all Bindings in MainWindow are addressed relative to its `DataContext` unless it is manually changed. (when you write `{Binding FirstName}` it means `DataContext.FirstName`)

```
<MainWindow xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Project1"
        ...>
    ...
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:NamesValidationRule MinimumLetters="3" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    ...
    <Button Content="Clear" Click="Clear_Clicked"/>
    ...
</MainWindow>
```

in StudentRecordsSystem:

note: don't forget to use dependencyProperty instead of normal property or else bindings won't work. and don't forget to derive the class (Student) from DependencyObject

```
 using System.Windows;
 ...
 public class Student : DependencyObject
 {
    //FirstName Dependency Property
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(Student), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
  }
```

and you won't need the 'Set' button anymore

Answer (score 0):

MainWindow should be like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Student myOnlyStudent;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myOnlyStudent = new Student()
    }

    private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myOnlyStudent.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Clear();
    }
}
```

If you insist on using a property with throwing an exception, then Student class must be like this:

```
public class Student
{
    private string mFirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return mFirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == true)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Please enter a first name");
            mFirstName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But for a starter at your level I would recommend you to use public instead private and skip properties (both visibility and properties are complicated):

```
public class Student { public string FirstName; }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.isNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text))
            throw new Exception("Please type first name!");
        myOnlyStudent.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
}
```